# How to enable java linter in Vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm a newbie in VsCode. My question is how can I enable the linter of java. I cannot see my errors. How can enable it? Jdk is installed and its already added environment path. What could be the problem?

Vscode version is  1.43
Java version is 1.8 u201

Comment: Shouldn't you just install it? Here is a link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=faustinoaq.javac-linter

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work :(

Comment: Install [Language Support for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) and you're done.